# How do I make an initial list with components?

Tags: r, list

I'd like to make a list to use in my function. I know that I can make an empty list with this.

```
list <- vector(mode = "list", length = 25)
```

What I'd like to do is make a list that is pre-loaded with three components per entry.

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 
[[2]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 

[[2]][[3]]
[1]
```

I'd tried to use `list(rep(list(c(NA, NA, NA)), 25))` but it adds the items all on the same level instead of adding them as separate components in each entry for the list.

Answer (score 2):

One option is `replicate`

```
lst1 <- replicate(5, vector(mode = "list", length = 3), simplify = FALSE)
```

---

Or with `rep`

```
rep(list(rep(list(NULL), 3)), 5)
```

Comment: Or with a nested `lapply`: `lapply(1:5, function(x) lapply(1:3, function(x) NULL))`

Comment: How do I apply names to the nested lists? I applied names to the top-level components with `names() `. I tried `lapply(my_lst, names, c("a", "b", "c"))` but it won't accept the vector as an argument.

Comment: You need either `lapply(lst1, setNames, c("a", "b", "c"))` or use `"names<-"`

Comment: Thank you. This is great learning and you really help make this place awesome

Comment: Is there an apply function that I can use to iterate over the lists in a list in a list? I added another `replicate` function so my list has three levels.

Comment: @goollan You can either use `lapply/sapply/vapply` or `map` from `purrr` or `walk2` etc.  as you have 3 levels, you may need `lapply(mylist, function(x) lapply(x, function(y) ..`

Comment: That's so cool. I was using a for loop with `for (i in 1:length(lst)){
    lst[[i]] <- lapply(lst[[i]], setNames, c("a", "b "c")) }` but I'll work on it and post my answer. Update: it was exactly like you said `lapply(lst, function(x) lapply(x, setNames, c("a", "b", "c")))`

Comment: @goollan  Try this `lst2 <- rep(list(rep(list(rep(list(NULL), 3)), 5)), 2);modify_depth(lst2, 2, set_names, c('a', 'b', 'c'))`